# Apache mod_deflate and chunked transfer

Tags: php, apache, chunked-encoding, mod-deflate

my website is running on Apache 2.2.24 + PHP 5.3.22. Apache is installed with mod_deflate and my .htaccess looks like this:

```
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript
</ifmodule>
```

And it works, files are being compressed before they are sent. I'm wondering if there is any way to use chunked transfers, ideally to send the head part of the html page to the browser.

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<?php
 ob_flush();
 flush();
 sleep(10);
?>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work when DEFLATE is on: the head is loaded after 10 secs, i.e. when the full page is received. 
On the other hand  when I tried to remove the option from the .htaccess file to turn off DEFLATE, the head is sent before the sleep() function is called.

With the up-to-date Apache and PHP versions, is there any way to make mod_deflate and chunked transfers work together? According to http://www.phpied.com/progressive-rendering-via-multiple-flushes/ it should be, but being rather an old article I would like to hear your thought before wasting my time.

Comment: *Even if* you could guarantee that the content is chunked and sent appropriately, you can't guarantee that the client will actually start rendering anything until the entire response is sent (varies by browser and by settings). If you have something that truly takes this long, load it via an AJAX request. Or, better yet, cache it.

Comment: Still, I would like to know if it's possible to make it using apache+php.